# Installing tidyverse package keep on not installing properly

Tags: r, rstudio

Version: RStudio 2022.07.0+548 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (34ea3031089fa4e38738a9256d6fa6d70629c822, 2022-07-06) for macOS
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_4_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.10 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

Hi,

I've been struggling for hours to solve this problem.
Here's what happens when I run  *install.packages("tidyverse")*

> install.packages("tidyverse")

```
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘dplyr’, ‘vctrs’, ‘dbplyr’
 There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation cli        3.2.0  3.3.0              TRUE dplyr      1.0.8  1.0.9              TRUE vctrs      0.4.0  0.4.1 TRUE dbplyr     2.1.1  2.2.1             FALSE tidyverse  1.3.1  1.3.2 FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) no trying URL 'https://mirror.rcg.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.tgz' Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 1151378 bytes (1.1 MB)
================================================== downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://mirror.rcg.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/dplyr_1.0.8.tgz' Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 1296204 bytes (1.2 MB)
================================================== downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://mirror.rcg.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/vctrs_0.4.0.tgz' Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 1729317 bytes (1.6 MB)
================================================== downloaded 1.6 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in   /var/folders/f6/_7s3zhw96r708r9tg_1kgzl80000gn/T//RtmpaUCrbe/downloaded_packages installing the source packages ‘dbplyr’, ‘tidyverse’

trying URL 'https://mirror.rcg.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/src/contrib/dbplyr_2.2.1.tar.gz' Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 670569 bytes (654 KB)
================================================== downloaded 654 KB

trying URL 'https://mirror.rcg.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.2.tar.gz' Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 702514 bytes (686 KB)
================================================== downloaded 686 KB

* installing *source* package ‘dbplyr’ ...
** package ‘dbplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dbplyr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/dbplyr’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency ‘dbplyr’ is not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tidyverse’ Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in   ‘/private/var/folders/f6/_7s3zhw96r708r9tg_1kgzl80000gn/T/RtmpaUCrbe/downloaded_packages’
```

It seems to work perfectly. But when I run this:

> library(tidyverse)

I get this:

```
Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
```

I tried many things from solutions I found on internet. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Uninstall R Studio from my desktop
- Make sure it was the most recent version
- Change CRAN mirror. I came
  back to the default mirror. See image:
  [image]

I'm quite discouraged by this. I can't keep going on my
work...

If someone could help me find the solution it would be very appreciated!

Comment: can you try installing packages separately i.e. `install.packages('dplyr')` instead of the whole group with tidyverse

Comment: I get this when I run library('dplyr'): Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.0.5

Comment: That message is not an error, but a friendly warning about which of the functions from base R are getting masked.  If you don't want to get the message, wrap with `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))`

Comment: My guess is that you have an old version of R and need to update. Current version is 4.2.1. RStudio is not the issue.

Comment: Ok... But the problem isn't solved. I need tidyverse to solve my function...

Comment: @Phil when I go «check for updates» I get: 'You're using the newest version of RStudio.'

Comment: You are confusing R and Rstudio. When you open RStudio, you should see in your console the version of R that you are currently using.

Comment: I see the error `namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required ` in the output you provided. Make sure to restart your R session and then try to update `cli` before anything else can load that package. Run `install.packages("cli")` and make sure that runs without error first.

Comment: @MrFlick. Thanks for your answer. It does run with error though... I'll only show the output of library because the install.package('cli') is too long to be accepted here. > library('cli')
Warning message:
package ‘cli’ was built under R version 4.0.5

Comment: @Phil. Can you explain it to me. Not so sure I'm following you here.

Comment: @Christophe Well you need to install a version of `cli >= 3.3.0`. If you are unable to share the output, it's going to be very difficult to help you understand why it isn't installing. Since it's a dependency, the `tidyverse` package will not install unless you get that working first. Running `library('cli')` will load the older version into memory which prevents you from updating it. That's why it needs to be updated before anything else can load it.

Comment: @Christophe https://wp.stolaf.edu/it/r-vs-rstudio/ Think of R as the engine of a car, RStudio as the inside of car to have an easier time to control the engine

Comment: Run `R.Version()$version.string`. What gets returned?

Comment: Likely the problem is that `cli` version 3.3.0 is not available in binary form.  In what you posted, you answered the question `Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) no`, so you won't get the latest of some packages.

Comment: I just checked, and `cli` is available as version 3.3.0 from a reliable mirror (`cloud.r-project.org`), but maybe not from the mirror you're using (`mirror.rcg.sfu.ca`).  So stop using that mirror.

Comment: I really do think OP is using an older version of R, and things will work themselves out if they update to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

- Just navigate to your bottom right console.
- click on packages
- search for tidyverse
- lastly, click on checkbox.
- then, re-run your code
  library(tidyverse)